# What is the image of this mobius transformation

Tags: complex-analysis, transformation

Consider the standard mapping $w=\frac{1}{z}$. What is the image of the "half" plane above the line whose imaginary part is $c$, for the three cases of $c\gt 0 , c=0 , c\lt 0$?

For $c=0$ obviously the image and preimage are the same. For the other two I think I get some sort of sector of a circle with $radius=\frac{1}{c}$ I think, but I don't know how to calculate the rest rigorously. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

$f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ is a Mobius transformation, which maps 'circles' to 'circles' and connected regions to connected regions. For $c=0$ we can see that it maps $\mathbb{R}$ (which is a circle of radius $\infty$) onto itself. $f(i)=\frac{1}{i}=-i$, and so the image of the upper half plane is the lower half.

Consider now $c>0$, the trick is to pick three points on the line that you can easily see where they go to. $f$ does not map any part of the line to $\infty$ and so $\mathrm{Im}(z)=c$ will be mapped to a 'conventional' circle. This circle includes the points:

$$f(ci)=\frac{-i}{c}$$
$$f(\infty)=0$$

For the last piece of information, note that $\mathrm{Im}(z)=c$ and $\mathrm{Im}(z)=0$ meet parallel at $\infty$, to see this imagine the preimages of $\mathrm{Im}(z)=0$, $\mathrm{Im}(z)=c$ on the Riemann sphere and note that unless they meet parallel they will intersect in two places. Thus the image of $\mathrm{Im}(z)=c$ is a circle in the lower half plane passing through $0$ and $\frac{-i}{c}$ which is tangent to the real axis. To see this visualised, pay around with [this applet](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/java/Mobius.html). To see whether the region above the line is mapped inside or outside this circle you could pick a point in the upper half plane and see where it is mapped to.